# XML parser interface to different languags

Tags: ruby, xml, json, parsing, xml-parsing

I'm working on writing a parser for a specific XML based document, which has a lot of rules and complicated interface.

I was going to write the parser in Ruby to parse it to JSON. Then realized, a lot of other people who use different languages like to use it. So I'm thinking of somehow creating a central rule system, where each language can wrap it and create it's own parser.

Any idea how to go about it?

Comment: Take a look at (nokogiri nokogiri.org).

Comment: I am looking for a non ruby parser, some wrapper that I can use nokogiri later with it

Answer (score 0):

It's unlikely to be productive for you to write your own XML parser from scratch.

As you anticipated, there has indeed been a need for parsing XML in every major language.  You can likely find libraries that implement multiple parsing models in any language you need.  Be aware of tree-based models such as [DOM](http://www.w3.org/TR/dom/), stream-based models such as [SAX](http://www.saxproject.org/), and pull-based models such as [StAX](http://stax.codehaus.org/).  Also consider XML processing models above the parsing level:  Declarative transformations (eg [XSLT](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt)) and databinding (eg [JAXB](https://jaxb.java.net/)).

The "central rule system" you envision has also already been realized in schemas (eg, [XSD](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-0/), [RelaxNG](http://relaxng.org/), [Schematron](http://xml.ascc.net/resource/schematron/), ...).

Comment: http://amolnpujari.wordpress.com/2012/03/31/reading_huge_xml-rb/
I also found ox is 5 times faster than nokogiri while reading a large xml.
Plus I have a wrapper written which simply allows you to search through large xml using ox, allows you to iterate with specified element.
https://gist.github.com/amolpujari/5966431